# Hovering on Google Chrome tab does not show the title?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I am designing a website where I have used a simple html page and inside it I have added a **title** tag. 
This title tag appears in every browser.

However, it does not work when I hover mouse over the tab in chrome.

Below is the sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Hello</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody suggest where am I going wrong ??

Comment: I have the latest version. It isn't working on any other machine as well.

Comment: I have two tabs open in my Chrome now; if the title is too long hovering over it will show the full title.

If the title is short enough to see in the tab the hover tooltip effect is not shown.

Answer (score 1):

Your title is too small to be seen over hover. Hover yellow block appears because you don't see the whole title of the tab

Comment: Thanks.. Just tried it with longer text. It showed the tool tip. But what if i have a smaller text.

Comment: you only care about the tab, or some dom element also?

Comment: Why would you want to show the title on hover if the title is big enough to fit into the tab?

Comment: Yes only about the tab. Not the dom element.

Answer (score 1):

Is it simply because the title value is too short to fire a tooltip?

Make the title `<title>really long title here .... Hello</title>` and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

Note that Chrome tab tooltips don't appear to work over TeamViewer or RDP:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389380#c78